# Searching on an object with different keys in Java

Tags: java, maps

I'm a developer transitioning from C++ to Java.So I still dont have all the expertise to getting stuff done the Java Way.
I have the following class

```
class Site
{
   String siteName;
   Integer siteId;
   Integer views;
   Integer searches;
}
```

I maintain 2 maps to search over the objects of this class(using sitename or siteid)

```
HashMap<String, Site> siteNameToSiteMap;
HashMap<Integer, Site> siteIdToSiteMap;
```

However going forward, I have to add a one more field called parentBrand to the class Site. This will force me to create another Map to be able to search over it.

```
HashMap<String, Site> parentBrandToSiteMap;
```

Such "indexing" variables might increase going ahead and thus also increase the number of maps I maintain.

I remember using Boost Multi-indexed container while solving a similar issue while developing in C++. Is there an equivalent well supported, well documented library in Java that I can use. If no, is there a way I can refactor my code to solve my problem.

Comment: From this point: *I have to add a one more field to the class called parentBrand* things become misunderstandable. Which class  `parentBrand`? Why `HashMap<String, Site>` and not `HashMap<String, ParentBrand>` and so on.

Comment: If the keys of the different maps are mutual exclusive (for example, a key in `parentBrandToSiteMap` cannot be equal to any key in `siteNameToSiteMap`), you can use a single `HashMap<String, Site>` to store all the associations (each `Site` will be indexed by up to 3 keys). This will require converting the site ID to String when putting it in the single map.

Comment: You might consider storing all this data in a database, which gives you the ability to create indices any way you like. If you're worried about I/O overhead, there are in-memory databases such as H2.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, an in-memory database would probably be my last resort. I was hoping using a library though. Its just easier get manager permissions and easier to integrate(I hope) when you have a library.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to avoid? Extra code? Duplication? Memory overhead?

Comment: @shmosel Extra code and duplication. Also coming from using the Boost multi-index container, the current way just seems like a primitive way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that there isn't a version of something like the boost multi-index containers available. (Maybe there is somewhere...) But its not too hard to hook up your own version in Java.

A rough, but working, version might look like this:

## The basic site object

I've used a slightly different Site object, just to keep things simple (and because I didn't have access to this post on the bus...)

```
    public class Site {
        Integer id;
        String name;
        String rating;
        // .. Constructor and toString removed for brevity
    }
```

## A wrapped version

I'm going to introduce some workhorse classes later, but they're a little ugly. This is just to show what the final interface would look like once you've wrapped it up a little:

```
class SiteRepository { 
   private final MultiMap<Site> sites = new MultiMap<>();
   public final AbstractMap<String, Site> byName = sites.addIndex((site)->site.name);
   public final AbstractMap<Integer,Site> byId = sites.addIndex((site)->site.id);
   public final AbstractMap<String,List<Site>> byRating = sites.addMultiIndex((Site site)->site.rating);
   public void add(Site s) { sites.add(s); }
}

SiteRepository repo = new SiteRepository();
repo.add(...);
Site site = repo.byId.get(1234);
repo.byId.forEach((Integer id, Site s) -> System.err.printf("   %s => %s\n", id, s));
```

## The MultiMap core

Probably should be called `MultiIndex` since `MultiMap` means something else...

```
    public static class MultiMap<V> {

        public static class MultiMapIndex<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
            @Override
            public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
                return map.entrySet();
            }
            HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();
       }


        public <K> MultiMapIndex<K,V> addIndex(Function<V, K> f) {
            MultiMapIndex<K,V> result = new MultiMapIndex<>();
            Consumer<V> e = (V v) -> result.map.put(f.apply(v), v);
            mappers.add(e);
            values.forEach(e);
            return result;
        }

        public <K> MultiMapIndex<K,List<V>> addMultiIndex(Function<V, K> f) {
            MultiMapIndex<K,List<V>> result = new MultiMapIndex<>();
            Consumer<V> e = (V v) -> {
                K key = f.apply(v);
                List<V> list = result.map.get(key);
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    result.map.put(key, list);
                }
                list.add(v);
            };
            mappers.add(e);
            values.forEach(e);
            return result;
        }

        public void add(V v) {
            values.add(v);
            mappers.forEach( e -> e.accept(v));
        }

        private List<Consumer<V>> mappers = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<V> values = new ArrayList<>();    
    }
```

## More low level examples

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a multi-map
        MultiMap<Site> multiMap = new MultiMap<>();

        // Add an index by Site.id
        MultiMapIndex<Integer, Site> byId = multiMap.addIndex((site)->site.id);

        // Add some entries to the map
        multiMap.add(new Site(1234,"A Site","A"));
        multiMap.add(new Site(4321,"Another Site","B"));
        multiMap.add(new Site(7777,"My Site","A"));

        // We can add a new index after the entries have been
        // added - this time by name.
        MultiMapIndex<String, Site> byName = multiMap.addIndex((site)->site.name);

        // Get a value by Id.
        System.err.printf("Get by id=7777 = %s\n", byId.get(7777));
        // Get a value by Name
        System.err.printf("Get by name='A Site' = %s\n", byName.get("A Site"));  

        // We can do usual mappy things with the indexes,
        // such as list the keys, or iterate over all entries
        System.err.printf("byId.keys() = %s\n", byId.keySet());
        byId.forEach((Integer id, Site s) -> System.err.printf("   %s => %s\n", id, s));

        // In some cases the map is not unique, so I provide a 
        // way to get all entries with the same value as a list.
        // in this case by their rating value.
        MultiMapIndex<String, List<Site>> byRating = multiMap.addMultiIndex((Site site)->site.rating);
        System.err.printf("byRating('A') = %s\n", byRating.get("A"));
        System.err.printf("byRating('B') = %s\n", byRating.get("B"));

        // Adding stuff after creating the indices is fine.
        multiMap.add(new Site(3333,"Last Site","B"));
        System.err.printf("byRating('A') = %s\n", byRating.get("A"));
        System.err.printf("byRating('B') = %s\n", byRating.get("B"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally a *pertinent* answer. But I think you should add some sort of definition of `F` to your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit scratchy sorry. But I got some time to polish it up on the bus. Major overhauled working answer provided. (Java 8 though)

Answer (score -2):

I think you can search your objects over List :

```
List<Site> sites;
for (Site s : sites) {
 if (s.getSiteName().equal(siteName)) {
 // do something
 }
 if (s.getSiteId().equal(siteId)) {
 // do something
 }
}
```

Comment: Why would OP want to search in O(n) instead of O(1)?

Answer (score -3):

You should create a Bean (Container) as Java is not requiring code optimisation as it will be optimised by the JIT compiler anyway.

```
public class SiteMap {
    String siteName;
    Integer siteId;
    String parentBrand;

.... Getters and setters ...
}

List<SiteMap> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you need to compare or sort then you can implement Comparable interface on the SiteMap class allowing you to sort the details if needed.

you can, if using Java 8 then also use Streams to filter or fetch the one you want. as there is a fetchFirst

```
SiteMap mysite = myList.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.siteName.equals("Amazon.com"))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
```

Comment: Why all the down votes with no comment on how to improve the answer or why it is not suitable. This is not how Stackoverflow is supposed to work, the method listed will work and you can search on ALL parameters by using the filter stream  i just showed the first one, you can also do .filter(e->e.siteId = 123)  as well

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the question. The OP creates maps in order to have O(1) access to his data. Beans have nothing to do with this, Sortable doesn't exist. Comparable has nothing to do with it. And searching using a stream is O(n).

Comment: But in Java using a List and streams is just as quick and unlike C++ where the OP is coming from, Java is not so execution optimised in code.

Comment: No, using a list is O(n), and using a HashMap is O(1). There is a significant difference as the number of items grows. It's most certainly **not** "just as quick". And compiler optimization, again, has nothing to do with it.

Comment: if the op is trying to get the millisecond improvements from specific data structures then is Java the language they should be using, Java should be written to make it readable and easy to modify not to get the last milisecond access time

Comment: @TheresaForster, just to give perspective there will be at least 10-20K objects of Site with my current dataset(expected to increase)

Comment: @PranavKapoor The way I showed is the usual Java Method, and good practice. if you have that many items then it may be better to store in a DB and recall from there as to load 20k items into memory will stress even a powerful computer. Also I used to work for a company who serves Websites for ALL the UK Premier League and we were at one point serving 15 million hits a second on just 3 clustered servers, running Java.